# @StringRes annotation fails for extension function return type

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, kotlin-extension

I have an extension function for an enum that return a string resource.
In order to make sure that the function only returns a valid String resource, I have annotated the function with `@StringRes`.

```
@StringRes
fun Fruit.getDescription(): Int {
    return when (this) {
        Fruit.APPLE -> R.string.apple_description
        Fruit.ORANGE -> R.string.orange_description
    }
}
```

However, even if I return a regular integer, a drawable or color resource etc, Android Studio doesn't seem to be flagging this as an issue. Which defeats the purpose of `@StringRes` annotation.

```
@StringRes
fun Fruit.getDescription(): Int {
    return when (this) {
        Fruit.APPLE -> 123
        Fruit.ORANGE -> R.drawable.some_icon
    }
}
```

How can I enforce the return type of my extension function to be a valid String resource ?

The annotation works for normal functions.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Noting yet @ankur